# Reuse Airflow hooks with kubernetes operator

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-operator

Is possible to import the hooks that airflow provided in the code (snowflake hook, aws hook, etc) in a kubernetes operator that run a python script?
I may have the wrong idea of how to work with airflow.

Example. I have Airflow running with a kubernetes cluster. Tasks of the dag are inside containers. One task takes some data from SQL and upload it to S3. If I want to do this in a python script inside container I need to code all this stuff (with the possible error and expend time) if I can reuse the libraries (hooks) that airflow has in the code I can save time and also, I'm supported for a lot of developers.

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @nodel No. Finally the best solution was create our hooks sorry.